# 404 error, but page loads fine?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to test my mobile site (wordpress) at http://gtmetrix.com/ But it is telling me there is a 404 error. The page loads fine for me on everything i have tried, and other sites work fine for me in GTMetrix. I'm not sure what to do about this to try and resolve the error.

http://textandmobilemarketing.mobi/home-2/

Copy of htaccess:

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName textandmobilemarketing.mobi
AuthUserFile /home/textand2/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/textand2/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help appreciated,

Ken

Comment: The page isn't "loading fine". that test site is correct and those pages are indeed reporting themselves as 404s. It looks fine through a browser, because browsers don't tell you a 404 is a 404. Search engines are not going to index them though. Something running on the server is set incorrect in doing this, but I can't really say anything more specific than "something running on the server" from the information here and by looking "from the outside".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon, but how would I go about determining what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Installed  **WP-DBManager** Plugin, 'Repaired DB' and everything went back to normal :)